# Grep multi line values

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am using the powershell command `net user userID /domain` to get the **Local Group Memberships** and **Global Group memberships** of a particular user. I am getting a lot of information from this command in which I require only the Local Group Memberships and Global Group memberships information.

Hence I am using the command `net user userID /domain | Out-String -Stream | Select-String “Global Group memberships”` to filter out only the  Global Group memberships information. Here occurs a problem such that I am getting only the data in one line where there are data present in multiple lines.

Kindly help me with the powershell command which filter out the entire list of Local Group Memberships and Global Group memberships of a particular user from this command.

If there is any other command which fetches only this information are also welcome. I tried many commands which didn't work out. I am using Windows server 2008 R2 and PSVersion 4.0. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `Get-ADUser` and the entire ActiveDirectory module for this, since you have a domain.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but did you tried " | format-list"

Comment: Powershell is not accepting the command "Get-ADUser". Seems like it does not support Get-ADUser. It is throwing error "Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" @Vesper

Comment: Tried " | format-list" too. Didn't work out :( @guiwhatsthat

Comment: `Format-List` does not help. The problem you are having is that the `net` command returns an array where each line is an element. Although the Global Group Memberships list spans many lines, only the first line contains that string and is returned. Check out [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/30/install-active-directory-management-service-for-easy-powershell-access/) for getting `Get-ADUser` to work. This will return an object, allowing you to use `Select` to get the properties you are after.

Comment: Either `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` if it's present, or add Windows features "features - role administration tools - AD DS - AD module for Powershell" if server, or first install RSAT with this module selected if non-server. HIGHLY useful thing to behold. If you're unable to install RSAT, then you'll have to parse data manually, or probably use VBScript that has access to LDAP out of the box. The module is the preferred way to use, though, check if you can acquire it as standalone fileset if you can't install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you a little closer to what you need (but this will be a single list with all group names and the title of the categories):

```
(((net user $env:USERNAME /domain | Out-String -Stream).trim() | Select-String '\*') -split '\*').trim() | Where {$_ -ne ''}
```

You could likely refine this solution further to produce two distinct lists instead.

**Explanation:**

- Uses `trim()` to remove empty lines from the string output.
- `Uses Select-String '\*'` to select all strings that have an asterisk character in them (as the output of groups all start with a *). The \ here is an escape character because regex.
- Uses `trim()` again to remove needless spaces around the group names.
- Uses `Where {$_ -ne ''}` to remove blank lines from the output.

I do agree that if you have a domain you'd get a better result with the Active Directory cmdlets (like `Get-ADUser`) which you need to have the AD Management Tools and/or the Active Directory PowerShell module installed to use.

The output of group names you get via `net user` is truncated so you're not getting a very true list.

Comment: Perfect !! This is what exactly I was looking for :)
Great explanation too. Makes a lot of sense to me.
Thanks a lot and Keep supporting !!!